# Magento 2.4 deploy command does not creating minify file when I am in production mode

Tags: magento2, javascript, error, static-content-deploy, minify

[image]

Magento 2.4.0: The static content deployment command does not create minify file when I am in production mode.
Getting error on below file. It's not creating so Magento cannot read it.

```
pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/requirejs-min-resolver.min.js
```

It's making some all other files minified except **requirejs-min-resolver.js** and **requirejs-config.js**.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Please give the proper permission for pub folder

Comment: All the folder and file permission are ok but doesn't work

Comment: is there any solution here? I'm facing the same issue when the mode is production and js merged and minified.

Answer (score -1):

- 
- Run the Below Command,
- bin/magento s:up
- bin/magento deploy:mode:set:production
- bin/magento c:f

Comment: Already tried above those commend but doesn't work